# The logon attempt failed when client and server are on the same computer

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service which exposes a service via tcp on an address like net.tcp://myComputerName:9900/MyService. I then have a client in a separate solution which connect to that address. The problem is, it only works when the server and client are on separate machines. Why is this, and how can I make it so that the client can run on any machine?

Comment: did you try running client and service as admin

Comment: Are you trying to connect locally after deployment on II or from visual studio ?

Comment: Tried running as admin. Didn't work. Visual Studio. Not IIS. It doesn't make sense that it will work on another computer, but not on the same computer. So obviously it's not that it doesn't work. Just some configuration I'm missing.

Comment: try to disable firewall, if u r in office network. then just try with some other network. I dont know but IT team might have done something

Comment: try to change proxy settings of browser too. which binding are you using ?

Comment: try <security mode="None" /> under <binding> tag in Web.Config

Comment: It works, but then fails because my code is designed to look at the WindowsID of the requester, which under No Security, is null. So I get "Object not set to an instance of an object." The null object is ServiceSecurityContext.Current == null. I need it to work with SecurityMode = Transport, and Transport.ClientCredentialType = Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe the easiest would be to have a condition if the client/server is on localhost, you can get the request IP by:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Comment: he is asking why ?

Comment: Doesn't help. System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null for me. Besides, I'm using TCP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding the following tag into the client endpoint config.  The service account an created account specifically for our services to run under.  I don't think there's anything special about it, just something IT setup for security purposes.

```
<identity>
    <userPrincipalName value="serviceaccount@domain.com" />
</identity>
```